# How can a nested while loop be O(n)?

Tags: javascript, big-o, nested-loops

I have this code here from the site www.interviewcake.com, which the site says is O(n), and upon asking for clarification from a team member at interview cake, they confirmed this to be true. Here is the code:

```js
function reverseWords(message) {

  // First we reverse all the characters in the entire message
  reverseCharacters(message, 0, message.length - 1);
  // This gives us the right word order
  // but with each word backward

  // Now we'll make the words forward again
  // by reversing each word's characters

  // We hold the index of the *start* of the current word
  // as we look for the *end* of the current word
  let currentWordStartIndex = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= message.length; i++) {

    // Found the end of the current word!
    if (i === message.length || message[i] === ' ') {

      // If we haven't exhausted the string our
      // next word's start is one character ahead
      reverseCharacters(message, currentWordStartIndex, i - 1);
      currentWordStartIndex = i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function reverseCharacters(message, leftIndex, rightIndex) {

  // Walk towards the middle, from both sides
  while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {

    // Swap the left char and right char
    const temp = message[leftIndex];
    message[leftIndex] = message[rightIndex];
    message[rightIndex] = temp;
    leftIndex++;
    rightIndex--;
  }
}
```

The explanation that the team member at interview cake said this:

*Yes, there's a nested loop that makes it look like it's O(n^2).

But, over the course of the problem, we can see that we're not reversing O( n ) characters in each inner loop ... we only reverse each character exactly twice. So, the total cost ends up being O(n).

This is a tricky one, because you have to look at the cost of all of the calls to reverseCharacters over the entire algorithm, instead of each call on its own.*

I am still confused though, as we are still looping through EACH character in the inner loop, and the bigger the string gets, the longer it would take to run the call.

I wanted to open this up to a different channel and see if I can get some additional insight on this and why its O(n) instead of O(n)^2.

To be completely clear, I would like an explanation on why the `reverseWords` function in the code provided above is O(n) and not O(n)^2

Comment: If you called reverseCharacters twice what would the BigO be? Is it any different if you call it in the entire string on each word boundary in that string?

Comment: Suppose you have `m` words of length `l_k` where `k` is 1 to `m` `Sum(l_k) = n`. Algorithm calls `reverseCharacters` for each word. Complexity of `reverseCharacters` is not `O(n)` it is "`O(rightIndex - leftIndex)`" basically `O(l_k)`. So you basically have `Sum(l_k)` ops i.e. `n`

Comment: It only increases linearly as the datalen increases. 10 words takes n time, 100 takes 10n, 1000 takes 100n. Compare if inner while loop was compareCharacters(to every word in the message) and the complexity of the inner while itself increases as datalen goes goes up. In the latter case, the datalen affects outer and inner loop making it O(n^2). (right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell in that code, the outer loop's job is to look for the end of each word. Once one is found (and only then), `reverseCharacters()` is called to reverse the characters in that word. So the big O of the two tasks add together (O(n) + O(n) = O(2n), which is still considered to be O(n)), rather than getting multiplied together (O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)) as you would normally expect them to do in nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed `O(n)`.

The confusement comes from the fact that `reverseCharacters()` is invoked in the inner loop. But, note WHEN is it invoked.

Let's look at some arbitrary character in the string, and see how often is it "touched".
Let our character be at index `i` for some `i`.

`reverseCharacters()` in the inner loop, is invoked once per word in the input string. The character `i` appears in exactly one word.

This means, the actual complexity of this code is:

```
T(n) = O(n       //    First reverseCharacters()
         +  n    // looping through all characters
         + l1    // reverseCharacters() on the first word
         + l2    // reverseCharacters() on the second word
         + ...   // and so on ...
         + lk)   // reverseCharacters() on the k'th (and last) word.
```

Since `l1 + l2 + ... + lk <= n`, this means, we have:

```
T(n) = O(n + n + l1 + l2 + ... + lk) <= O(n + n + n) = O(n)
```